# Button only submitting if JavaScript disables it with timer to prevent double submit

Tags: javascript, button

I want a button to be disabled (only if Validators from "grpRegister" validation group aren't triggered) to prevent double submitting. I used JavaScript to disable the button on click. But that ALSO started to prevent the form from being submitted (with no validators triggered). I managed to work around it adding a small timer before the disabling of the button. This is the code:

```
    var btn = document.getElementById("btnRegister");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (Page_ClientValidate("grpRegister")) {
            var myVar = setInterval(function () { btn.disabled = true; clearInterval(myVar); }, 100);
        }
    });
```

With only 100ms delay, it worked. So my question is, <strike>ANY timer value works? And</strike> why this is happening, it can't be disabled immediately?

**EDIT**:

Just *1ms* is enough to make it work. The following code **DON'T** work:

```
    var btn = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnRegistar");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (Page_ClientValidate("Registar")) {
            btn.disabled = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: not an answer, but `setTimeout` is a better way to do that, because you don't need to clear it (think of setTimeout as a "oneshot" setInterval - which is what you've coded)

Comment: Why could you not disable it immediately? Just don't use a timer at all.

Comment: That's my question, it didn't make sense to me too. But i tested a lot and without timer it seems like is going to do the postback but then stops. Without the JavaScript code everything works fine.

Comment: Don't put the listener on the `click` event of the button, put it on the `submit` event of the form.

Comment: I think this problem is specific to you, it seems to work fine for me.  Some other code must be interfereing, do you want to create a codepenn or plunk and link your issue?